# Is there a standard function code like `lambda x, y: x.custom_method(y)`?

Tags: python

I know that I can call magic methods using functions from `operator` module, for example:

```
operator.add(a, b)
```

is equal to

```
a.__add__(b)
```

Is there a standard function for calling a custom method (like `operator.methodcaller` but also accepts method arguments when called)?
Currently I have code like this:

```
def methodapply(name):
    """Apply a custom method.

    Usage:
        methodapply('some')(a, *args, **kwargs) => a.some(*args, **kwargs)

    """
    def func(instance, *args, **kwargs):
        return getattr(instance, name)(*args, **kwargs)
    func.__doc__ = """Call {!r} instance method""".format(name)
    return func
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it is still called [`operator.methodcaller()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html#operator.methodcaller):

> Return a callable object that calls the method *name* on its operand. If additional arguments and/or keyword arguments are given, they will be given to the method as well. For example:
>
> - After `f = methodcaller('name')`, the call `f(b)` returns `b.name()`.
> - After `f = methodcaller('name', 'foo', bar=1)`, the call `f(b)` returns `b.name('foo', bar=1)`.

This inverts the chain a little from what you want; you need to tell `methodcaller()` up-front what arguments to pass in.

There is no standard-library callable that'll build a method caller that accepts both the instance and the arguments.

However, if your sequence of objects you are going to apply this to is homogenous, you can instead just use the *unbound* method; unbound methods take `self` as the first argument. So this works:

```
from itertools import 
map(str.split, list_of_strings, [','] * len(list_of_strings), range(len(list_of_strings)))
```

which will split strings on commas with a growing limit; each time `map()` calls `str.split()` (an unbound method), it'll pass in a `str` object from the `list_of_strings` list, a `','` string, and an integer argument ranging from `0` to `len(list_of_strings) - 1`.

Comment: Doesn't work for me: `TypeError: methodcaller expected 1 arguments, got 3`.

Comment: @ecatmur: no, the methodcaller object doesn't take the arguments afterwards, it takes them up-front.

Comment: So that doesn't answer the question, then.

Comment: It's a little tricky keeping up with your edits! Using the unbound method will only work if the object is of a known type; it won't work with overrides or duck typing.

Comment: @ecatmur: hrm, editing error, there was a part missing in the sentence that states the unbound method only works for a homogenous list.